# Web view shows blank/white page after loading URL when using WIFI in Android

Tags: android, url, webview

My webview loads the URL which I load on to it in both Android emulator and device (using 3G).

When I load the same web page with wifi it returns a blank/white page.

```
    mWebView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {

            Log.d("ON RECEIVE ERROR", failingUrl + " --- " + description);

        }       })
    mWebView.invalidate();
        mWebView.loadUrl(Url);
```

And I have done any changes/added something in manifest for this.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tfe"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="0.0.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.xxx.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.SampleApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show me your manifest.xml file and your code

Comment: @ Simple Plan: Pls look into the code i have added and help me

Comment: you need to implement `webViewclient shouldOverrideUrlLoading(.....)` method

Comment: @Simple Plan  This doesn't seem to help me. I had this method before and I commented it out

Comment: yup also post your manifest.xml file.

Comment: @Simple Plan Pls check my manifest file that I have added

Comment: Don't use this in production since the Play Store rejects every app including this workaround

Answer (score 2):

Please add

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) 
{
handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

inside  `setWebViewClient`.

Comment: Tried this. It doesn't help me:(

Comment: That's a payment related url. Its confidential one

Answer (score 1):

There are possible reasons causing "WebView goes blank after finish loading page":

1. If your WebView part defined in the layout xml file has dimensions like

   ```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   ```

   or

   ```
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ```

   Then after the page is loaded, the content is defined and WebView tries to "wrap" it, thus in some cases reduces the view's dimensions into 0dp and make your WebView invisible.
   Solution: change all those into fill_parent

   ```
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   ```
2. This may be caused by an SSL certification error. Try this:

   ```
   public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
       handler.proceed();
   }
   ```

Comment: Setting the webview height to "match parent" solved my problem. Thank you.